# Chapters on odd pages in single-sided document

Tags: book-design

I must use the `book` class but I want the same margins in all pages, so I wrote:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
```

However, I still need the chapters to begin on odd pages. Is it possible?

Comment: If it's only to have the same margins in all pages — I suppose this means oddside margin and even side margin are equal, just write `\usepackage[hmargin= …]{geometry}` in your preamble.

Comment: Just to amplify @Bernard's comment: use the `geometry` setting *instead of* the `[oneside]` setting.

Comment: Is there any news here?

Comment: @Bernard You should post that as answer

Comment: @Bernard Can you write an answer?

Comment: @egreg: Your wish is my command.

Answer (score 2):

To have equal left and right margins, and more generally to customise the pages layout, the simplest and most intuitive way is to leave the book class with the default options (`twoside`, `openright`), and load the `geometry` package, at least in standard classes, with option, say,

```
[hmargin=3cm] or [textwidth=15cm, hcentering]
```

You also can load geometry without any option, and set them via

```
\geometry{hmargin=3cm}, \geometry{textwidth=15cm, hcentering}
```